# How to grant access to all the CRD's in rancher kubernetes (RKE)?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, rancher

I have a requirement to grant access to all the CRD's to a user in k8s. What verb or API I should use? I tried with crd, CRDS but nothing is helping. TIA